# How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\pi\left(\frac{4x}{3}\right)}{\frac{x}{3\ln x}}=4$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I'm a member of a Facebook-based mathematics group. Recently, one of the members made a post detailing an observation he made in his free time, namely that $\pi(4x/3)-\pi(x)$ (here, $\pi(x)$ denotes the prime-counting function) is approximated rather closely by $\frac{x}{3\ln(x)}$. Knowing about the prime number theorem, I immediately recognized that this might be due to the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{x/\ln(x)}=1$.

This guess turned out to be partially correct. It turns out that these two are in fact asymptotic, in the sense that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(4x/3)-\pi(x)}{x/(3\ln x)}=1$, but I haven't been able to prove this completely. Here's my reasoning so far:

The limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(4x/3)-\pi(x)}{x/(3\ln x)}$ can be found by evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(4x/3)}{x/(3\ln x)}$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{\pi(x)}{x/(3\ln x)}$. The latter of these is easy to compute (just multiply the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{x/\ln(x)}=1$ by $-3$ and rewrite $3$ as $\frac{1}{1/3}$). Consulting WolframAlpha, one finds that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(4x/3)}{x/(3\ln x)}=4$, so

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi\left(\frac{4x}{3}\right)-\pi(x)}{\frac{x}{3\ln(x)}}=4-3=1$$

My question is this: how can I prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(4x/3)}{x/(3\ln x)}=4$? I imagine the prime number theorem will come into play here, but I'm not sure how. In particular, I don't know how the $\frac{4}{3}$ factor that appears in the argument of $\pi(x)$ affects the limit, much less how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac {\pi(4x/3)}{(4x/3)/\ln(4x/3)}=1$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac {\pi(4x/3)}{\left.\dfrac{4x}3\right/\left(\ln x+\ln\frac43\right)}=1$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac {\pi(4x/3)}{\left.\dfrac{4x}3\right/\ln x }=1$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac {\pi(4x/3)}{x/(3\ln x )}=4$$

Comment: I was thrown off a little by the lack of division symbols next to the $\ln(x)$ terms, but quickly recognized that it was likely a typo. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance and pointing out the typo., which I have corrected

Comment: You might be interested in `$\left.\dfrac{4x}3\right/\ln x$` $\left.\dfrac{4x}3\right/\ln x$

Comment: Thanks, @CalvinKhor; I edited in your formatting suggestion